# Loggly: Grouping using LogglyBatchAppender?

Tags: logback, loggly

We have a Scala Play app and we are using the [LogglyBatchAppender](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Loggly). But, all our environments (dev, staging, prod) logs are being mixed up on loggly. [This](https://www.loggly.com/docs/source-groups/) says we can group by sources or hostnames or tags but hostname info is not being attached to outgoing loggly messages and this [wiki](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Loggly) page says nothing about how to attach tags in the `LogglyBatchAppender` (it does mention how to tag using the slower `LogglyAppender`). What is the best way to see different host/env logs in loggly if we are using the LogglyBatchAppender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can set the endpointUrl in LogglyBatchAppender.  When you set the URL make sure the include the tag at the end of it. You can tag them for dev/staging/prod. This way you can use Loggly's source groups.

Example with a prod tag. Remember to replace with your own customer token:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="logglyAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.loggly.LogglyBatchAppender">
        <endpointUrl>http://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/YOUR-CUSTOMER-TOKEN/tag/prod/</endpointUrl>
        ...
    </appender>
</configuration>
```